# iPhone application lags after launching and dismissing MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, allocation, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, lag

I have an application that uses a table view controller to display some items, after clicking on one of those items you may select to email this item. Once that happens I use the code provided by apple "MailComposer", and send the mail. However after this the scrolling in the table view is not as smooth as before.

I checked with "Leaks" and there are no leaks in my code, however there is a great deal of object allocation when the modal view controller for the MFMailComposeViewController, and when i dismiss my controller, all that object allocation is still there. How can i get rid of all that object allocation?. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

-Oscar

UPDATE:

I have realized the lag only happens once you click on the To: textfield on the MFMailComposeViewController and type something, once something has been typed there will be a memory leak and the application will be sluggish. This exact same thing also happens in Apple's Mail Composer. I am using the simulator maybe this is why?. Does anyone else have a simmilar experience?

The way I am pressenting my controller is:

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSString *mailSubject = appDelegate.mailTitle;
    NSString *mailBody = appDelegate.mailLink;

    NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href='%@'>%@</a>", mailBody, mailBody];

    [picker setSubject:mailSubject];

    // Set up recipients
    //NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"somemail@hotmail.com"]; 
    //NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
    //NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

    //[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    //[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];    
    //[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

    // Attach an image to the email (Warning this causes a memory leak aknowledged by Apple)
    //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"news_icon" ofType:@"png"];
    //NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    //[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"rainy"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    [picker setMessageBody:formattedString isHTML:YES];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

and dimissing it here:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    ....
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: you should show some code of how you are instantiating and presenting the mail compose view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known memory leak in `MFMailComposeViewController` class (as of iOS 4.2 SDK). The leaks can be even seen in the **MailComposer** sample project by Apple. Try to run the app with Allocations instrument and notice the Overall Bytes growing up every time you click cancel and show the composer again.

See below for the similar discussion:

1. http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2158170
2. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/23510?tstart=15
3. https://devforums.apple.com/message/121093#121093

Comment: Some of those discussions are quite dated, but I'm still seeing the issue on iOS 4.2 SDK as well. Does anyone know if there's a fix planned for this?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue and have not idea for a fix. Only leaving the app and launching mail might solve this - while not providing a nice user experience (but the sluggish or lagging UI is still worse imho)

Comment: I tried to find some other solution, but only found following behaviour: after the MFMailComposeViewController has been dismissed, put the app to the background and awake it right away. In my case the view's scrolling was ok after this (the app was not restarted, but only re-activated).

Comment: @marcus: How would you put an app into background? And how would you awake it again? I think you'll have to step into private API territory  which would be a sure way to get your app rejected by Apple. Let me know otherwise

Comment: @MyCSharpCorner with my last comment I just described a behavior I noticed while testing around. When I put the app to background manually by pressing home button and launching it again by selecting it's icon, the scrolling issue was not apparent any more.

Comment: @marcus ok, thanks for the clarification. By the way, does anyone know if the memory leak in MFMailComposeViewController has been fixed by Apple in iOS 5 SDK release?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use

```
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

and not

```
controller.delegate = self;
```